# Issue when initializing a double-typed array by zero

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I want to create an array of type `double` and initialized it by `0.0`. I did the following:

```
double sum[3];

sum = {0.0};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    printf("%f ", sum[i]);
}
```

However, the compiler says it is wrong `error: expected expression`! Why? and how to fix it?

Comment: You initialize when an object is declared, otherwise it is an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize all elements in the declaration...

```
double sum[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

or one at a time in your loop...

```
double sum[3];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof( sum ) / sizeof( double ); i++)
{
  sum[i] = 0.0;
  printf("%f ", sum[i]);
}
```

Comment: In any compound object (such as an array or struct), if you initialize any one value (generally the first), all other values are initialized to zero by default. You can initialize each element individually, but if you are initializing to zero, only one need be given, e.g. `double sum[3] = {0.0};` (also, nothing wrong with the use of `sizeof`, but `sizeof sum/sizeof *sum` will suffice.)

Answer (score 3):

You're not initializing, you're *assigning* the value. Moreover, you cannot *assign* anything to an *array* type, at all.

The LHS operand of an assignment operator should be a modifiable lvalue, and an array (*array name*) is not a modifiable lvaule. So you cannot *assign* anything to an array.

Try something like

```
double sum[3] = {0.0};
```